# Python Tools for Visual Studio: Way to remap dash key to underscore?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping, ptvs

Using Visual Studio 2010 with [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/).  I find typing an underscore in python variable names inconvenient.

Is there a way to remap the <kbd>-</kbd> (dash key) to the underscore and <kbd>Shif+-</kbd> (shift + dash) to a dash?  Similar to [Smart-dash mode in Emacs](http://malsyned.net/smart-dash.html) (although it doesn't need to be that fancy a simple remapping when working on a python project would be fine).  I don't mind a solution that uses a 3rd party tool such as auto hot key if that's the only way and works reasonably well.